# Creating a PHP server with Apache and Kohana

Tags: php, apache, kohana

I am completely new in the server and PHP world.
I would like to upload a ready-made REST back-end that is written in the Kohana Framework to my local server and write front-end to it.

I made a server on the guide with Apache, PHP and PhpMyAdmin.

Since I have never worked with PHP and Apache, could you suggest a script, steps for setting up a backend that will send me JSON from the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS? What did you do so far during the Apache, PHP installation?

Answer (score 1):

1. use latest Kohana 3.3 or https://github.com/koseven + [Controller_REST](https://github.com/koseven/koseven/blob/devel/system/classes/KO7/Controller/REST.php)
2. don't use "all in" route
3. check [existed code](https://github.com/search?q=kohana%20rest)